# Difference between bash-script and cocoa code with OpenSSL

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bash, sha1

I try get SHA1-sugnature with bash-script and cocoa-code.

Bash-script:

```
echo -n "RF001" | openssl dgst -sha1
```

gives me:

```
3eb0c58821e30a235a402308acff357e6f3d9f41
```

Cocoa:

```
const unsigned char buffer[] = "RF001";
size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);

uint8_t md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(buffer, buffer_size, md);

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:md length:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSLog([data description], nil);
```

writes to console:

```
<3ab9d9cc ece56e3f 48d00c3f f2a9216a 5b74bbce>
```

Why are not these two results same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was error in Cocoa-snippet.
There is good code:

```
const char* buffer = "RF001";

uint8_t md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1((uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer), md);

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:md length:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSLog([data description], nil);
```